# Order of messages in Azure Service Bus

Tags: c#, azureservicebus

My Azure Service Bus has only one topic and there is only one publisher. The publisher sends messages to the topic with this code:

```
public void Publish<T>(T messageObject)
{
    var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(messageObject);
    var message = new ServiceBusMessage(jsonString);
    message.ApplicationProperties["messageType"] = typeof(T).Name;

    serviceBusSender.SendMessageAsync(message);
}
```

In my application code, I call this method consecutively to send `message1`, `message2` and `message3`, respectivly. However, when I go to Azure, and receive messages on Service Bus Explorer, I see the messages' order is not necessarily the same.

Is  this behavior expected? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Please see this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/ordering-messages-in-azure-service-bus/. HTH.

Comment: Yes, it is a normal behavior. Overwrite the message Id with your id and then you can order them and use them with the desired purpose.

Comment: Have you considered using a queue?

Comment: @DA can you please elaborate a bit on why/how overwriting message ID will enforce the ordering of messages?

Comment: @PeterBons I have multiple subscribers, so I can't use a queue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created the non-partitioned entity then you can enable the Support ordering feature as [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/advanced-features-overview#support-ordering).

> The Support ordering feature allows you to specify whether messages
> that are sent to a topic will be forwarded to the subscription in the
> same order in which they were sent. This feature doesn't support
> partitioned topics. For more information, see
> TopicProperties.SupportOrdering in .NET or
> TopicProperties.setOrderingSupported in Java.

In case of partitioned entity your can leverage the session while sending the message. A session will give you related messages in the exact arrival order if you process them in sequence, meaning using one thread and without prefetching. When the consumer fails processing a message and abandons it, that message will again be the first to be delivered until it exceeds its delivery count.